# treat parameter as global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I want to create a function that gets a global variable as a parameter and changes it after a timeout.

```
function change(variable, value, time)
{
    setTimeout(function() { variable= value; }, time);

}
```

I do not know what variable is in advance.

problem is when I do this the assignment doesn't hold for outside the function.

How can I tell the function that var is global?

Comment: To make it work, you would use `window[varName] = value`, but don't do that.  You shouldn't be abusing global variables like this.

Comment: `variable` really isn't that much better, except for not being a reserved word.

Comment: An interesting answer here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178728/passing-a-global-variable-to-a-function