# Have a function change outside/global variables in a generic way

Tags: javascript

I want to write a generic way to change properties inside a function. It actually happens inside a function, but I think the problem can be simplified in the following way.

```
var showItemA = true;
var showItemB = true;
var showItemC = false;

var switchToggle = function (toggleTarget) {
    toggleTarget = !toggleTarget
    // Do other stuff
    console.log(toggleTarget);
    //false
};

switchToggle(showItemA);
console.log(showItemA);
//true; but I want it to be false
```

I am well aware of [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872006/how-to-change-value-of-global-variable-inside-of-function), but I need it to be generic to handle different properties. Is there a way to throw outside variables or properties at a function and have it change their value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use an object? This is essentially the same as using `window` as in your found answer, but doesn't unnecessarily pollute the global space with loads of new variables.

```
var obj = {};
var key = 'showItemA';
obj[key] = true;

var switchToggle = function (toggleTarget) {
    obj[toggleTarget] = !obj[toggleTarget];
    console.log(obj[toggleTarget]);
    // false
};

switchToggle(key);
console.log(obj[key]);
// false
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ndvs239f/)

Comment: That works, just found the solution independently. Feel free to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @RoyPrins, just added an additional comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here:

[Passing a global variable to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178728/passing-a-global-variable-to-a-function)

The trick is not to pass the value, but rather the reference to the variable to the function. Makes sense.