# Passing a reference of a global variable to a function

Tags: javascript, global-variables, parameter-passing

Is it possible to send a link to a global variable to a function in JavaScript?
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178788) says no, but I cannot believe, there is no workaround.

What I mean is something like the following. It is not working, but it shall explain what I mean:

```
var data_1;
var data_2;

fillValue(data_1,"First");
fillValue(data_2,"Second");

function fillValue(link2GlobalVar, value){
    link2GlobalVar = value;
}   

console.log(data_1);
console.log(data_2);
```

It would be great if it was possible to output in the console

```
First
Second
```

Do you know a trick to send global variables to functions and change them within them like this?

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/9288bgaq/)

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9288bgaq/1/**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitive values aren't passed by reference.
Objects are.

If you wrap the globals in an object, you'll be able to modify its properties from a function:

```js
var data_1 = {};
var data_2 = {};


fillValue(data_1,"First");
fillValue(data_2,"Second");

function fillValue(link2GlobalVar, value){
    link2GlobalVar.value = value;
}   

document.write(data_1.value + "<br/>" +data_2.value);
```

Other than that, `this`, should be more portable than `window`. (Works both in the browser and on `nodejs`). You can't use it from inside functions (that aren't called with new) if you're in strict mode, but you can use it in global scope to get a reference to the global scope.

```js
"use strict";
var data_1;
var data_2;
var global = this;  //get a reference to the global object
    
fillValue("data_1","First");
fillValue("data_2","Second");

function fillValue(globalVariableName, value){
    //`this` instead of `global` would work here only if you're not in strict mode
    global[globalVariableName] = value;
}   

document.write(data_1 + "<br/>" +data_2);
```

Comment: I like this better than my own answer.  It's probably closer to what the OP wants.

Comment: I wouldn't actually use `this`.  It doesn't work in "strict mode".  From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript): "in browsers it's no longer possible to reference the `window` object through `this` inside a strict mode function."

Comment: Thanks for the hint with node.js!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @RocketHazmat. I've amended the second solution to make it work around that. Works on my chromium, firefox, and node.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript doesn't have references in the same way other languages do.  When you do `fillValue(data_1,"First");` you are passing `data_1` by value.  So, you can't update `data_1` because in the function all you have is a *copy* of the data.

If these variables are *global*, then you can do what the linked answer suggests and pass the variable name:

```
fillValue("data_1", "First");
fillValue("data_2", "Second");

function fillValue(link2GlobalVar, value){
    window[link2GlobalVar] = value;
}
```

UPDATE:
In JavaScript, if you pass an *object* as a parameter, then *it* is actually passed by reference.  You can try something like this:

```
var datas = {};

fillValue(datas, "data_1", ,"First");
fillValue(datas, "data_2", "Second");

function fillValue(obj, key, value){
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: @blex - it's the same answer, this is just explained better.

Comment: @adeneo sorry I got carried away, thinking OP was already passing a string as the variable name, as in [the answer he linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178728/passing-a-global-variable-to-a-function/18178788#18178788). +1

Comment: @blex - Actually, Crayons answer seems to be wrong as it's **not** passing a string, and that answer won't work.

Comment: @adeneo Ah, true, it's like saying `window[undefined] = value;`

Comment: If we don't want to assume there is a browser, and thus, a `window` object, would this be better? http://jsfiddle.net/j90kurvy/

Comment: I'm willing to concede (and delete my answer) to the point of it being passed as a variable reference instead of a string (though really I blame OP for that, not my answer) but re: "maybe not a browser" I think y'all looking too far into it lol

Answer (score 0):

this question seems a little crazy but you could pass the name of the global as string and then set with an eval:

`function blah(nameAsString, val){ eval("window." + name + " = " + val);}`

even crazier! :)

Comment: This is a potential security hole (and a huge one at that) unless you sanitize things.

Comment: Please don't actually do this.  Why would you do `"window." + name` inside `eval()` over `window[name]` without `eval()`?

Comment: The option using eval is actually a good option if a variable should be constructed using strings. I tried to make this example running (http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/7ft65ma5/) but I was not successful. Any ideas to fix this?