# How do I brake While-Loop with a function defined before?(plain Java Script)

Tags: javascript

I´m about to create a simple game, but the game-loop isn´t working yet. The while-loop does not break ,if I call the end_game function and keeps printing 'a'. I realy could not figure out what´s wrong with it. Thank you guys.

```js
var game_status = true;

var end_game = function end_game(){
                    game_status = false;
                    return game_status;
                    };

var game_loop = function game_loop(game_status, end_game){
                  while(game_status == true){
                        console.log('a');
                        end_game();
                  }
              };

function call_gameloop(){
    game_loop(game_status,end_game);
};
```

```html
<div id = 'play_field' onclick='call_gameloop();'></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a global variable to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178728/passing-a-global-variable-to-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`game_status` variable in `game_loop()` function is local to the function and is different from the globally declared variable.

`end_game()` function modifies global variable and therefore does not break the above loop.

To make things work, don't pass `game_status` parameter to `game_loop()` function like you didn't pass to `end_game()` function.

Comment: Hey. It´s working fine now thank you very much mate :)